# Is it possible to generate a file with javascript and send it to server?

Tags: javascript, css, server

Is it possible to generate a file with javascript and send it to server? I have a section in my web page where the user can modify the style of its page, and I want to generate the css file with that style configuration before to send it to the server. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Why does it need to be a bonafide `.css` file before posting it to the server? Why not just send the file contents you already have in the page (if I'm understanding correctly?), and then use that to generate the file server-side?

Comment: See [`Blob` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob), [`File` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File), [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), [XHR binary data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript create multiple files zip them up and send to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701383/javascript-create-multiple-files-zip-them-up-and-send-to-server)

Comment: Send the data to the server and generate the file there ... You don't mention what server side script you use.

Answer (score 2):

```
var blob = new Blob(["css content"],{type:"text/css"});
var formData = new FormData()
formData.append("file",blob,"fileName"); 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
xhr.onload = function(e) { /**get answer from server*/};
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: This is nice. Just be aware that `Blob` isn't available in IE<=9, and no versions of IE support `json` as the response type of `XHR` requests when `FormData` is appended.