# Generating a File and Uploading it via an HTML Form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

A client requires that the (client-side only) web app which I am developing uploads a JSON file generated by the app. I have no access to the code of the server-side script which handles the saving of the file to the correct directory. I only have access to the following HTML form which posts to the server-side script:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" acceptcharset="UTF-8" method="post" style="clear:left" action="/ajax/FileUploader.html?idToUse=attachment-1438128389605&amp;decompress=false&amp;outputLocation=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Ftomcat%2Fwebapps%2FROOT%2Fimages%2F">
  <input size="50" type="file" name="attachment-1438128389605">
  <div style="padding-top:5px">
    <div style="display:none; margin-left:60px; margin-top:10px; float:left" class="file-type-not-permitted">This file type is not permitted </div>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" class="ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled input-type-submit-small" role="button" aria-disabled="true" disabled="">
  </div>
</form>
```

My client-side app already has access to the server and this particular HTML form via HTTP authentication.

Is it possible to generate the JSON file and attach it as file to the form? The requirement is that this is all done through client-side JavaScript.

Comment: If it's client side only, it cannot 'generate a file'. Do you have to send a file to the server, or can you send a JSON object (not a file)?

Comment: you can send JSON data from the client to the server.

Comment: @azium Unfortunately I have no control over how FileUploader.html receives the JSON data; it appears to expect a file, rather than a JSON object.

Comment: This is a rather strange scenario. For science though, the only thing I can suggest is to create a very simple server side service that accepts json data, creates a file and sends it back to you, or rather, sends it to the endpoint on your behalf

Comment: @azium Yes, it is not ideal. The current requirement is that the upload is done via client side JavaScript. If I had more control over the server setup I would do something like your suggestion.

Comment: Well you can't make files on the client alone so your task is impossible. What i'm suggesting is to write your own server side service, which you should be able to do without touching the one you can't touch.

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592127/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-file-with-javascript-and-send-it-to-server/31592624#31592624

Comment: You CAN create file only at client side!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the [FormData interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for XMLHttpRequest. Here is my solution:

```
// Set the folder path where the file will be uploaded:
var encodedFolderPath = 
  encodeURIComponent('/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/images/');

// Set the file name of the file to be uploaded:
var encodedFileName = encodeURIComponent('my_file' + '.json');

// Set the file input name to a unique value (required by the server):
var attachment = "attachment-" + (new Date()).getTime(); 

// Construct the form data:
var formData = new FormData();

// Construct a JavaScript file-like object
var content = "{ json content here }";
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "application/octet-stream"});
formData.append(attachment, blob, encodedFileName);

// Set the upload URL:
var uploadURL = "";
uploadURL = '/ajax/FileUploader.html?idToUse=' + attachment + 
  '&decompress=false&outputLocation=' +
  encodedFolderPath + '&fileName=' + encodedFileName;

// Send the request:
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", uploadURL);
request.send(formData);
```