# Send files without button event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, file

Is it possible to send files without choosing them with button click and searching folder? I have app written in ReactJS that chooses files on button click, but for testing purposes I need to have 'hardcoded' files so that I don't need to make any actions in my application. The question is: can I do something like that within React app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't read files from the client computer, even if you have the full path. That would be a major security flaw if javascript could access client files without the explicit consent of the user (provided by the browser).

You can, however, create a file within javascript with hardcode content and send it by http request. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592127/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-file-with-javascript-and-send-it-to-server) you have a solution on how to achieve this.